# Perl: assign array to hash values?

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

I was trying to initiate a hash that have 7 NAs as values.

This is what I have:

```
values %hash = ("NA") x 7;
print join("\t",values %hash),"\n";
```

I got this error:

```
Can't modify values in scalar assignment at line 22, near "7;"
```

Apparently, I can't do this with values of hash although I can assign array to hash keys

```
keys %hash = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g"];
```

Why is it working for keys but not values for hash assignment?

Comment: So the big question is: Why do you want a hash with 7 NAs in it?

Comment: @LenJaffe : OP wanted a hash with 7 values in it.

Comment: Yes. I saw that. But Why a hash? OP created a hash using list assignment.  I'm trying to get a level deeper to find out what OP is actually trying to accomplish.

Comment: i need to process the hash later... to use the keys in the hash

Comment: I got around it with the answers from this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3556052/how-do-i-initialize-values-in-a-hash-without-a-loop

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From `perldoc -f keys`:

> Used as an lvalue, "keys" allows you to increase the number of hash buckets allocated for the given hash.  This can gain you a measure of efficiency if you know the hash is going to get big.

I.e. this method is not useful to set the keys, only to allocate space for a certain number of entries. When using a reference as the number, the result will probably be something ridiculously large that will eat most of your memory – not exactly recommended.

To initialize a hash with some values, you *have* to specify the required keys. But you can use a *slice* as an lvalue:

```
my %hash;
@hash{1..7} = ("NA") x 7;
```

Note: an lvalue is a value that can be used on  the left side of an assignment.

Answer (score 1):

A hash has two parts to it, keys and values. e.g.:

```
my %hash = ( a => 1, b => 2, c => 3 );
```

Here, the keys are 'a', 'b' and 'c'. The values are 1, 2 and 3.

If you look at what [`keys`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/keys.html) and [`values`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/values.html) do, they (unsurprisingly) return the keys and values of the hash respectively.

They are not meant to set the values or keys of a hash, merely to retrieve.

---